# How to return total count and including records while using Search Pipe in angular?

Tags: angular, angular-pipe

I am  implementing search functionality using angular pipe, my requirement is to return the search results i.e array of objects and total count i.e total number of search results. I tried returning multiple paramters I am getting count number but it is returning accurate result but I am duplicate row gets displayed i.e if search result count is 1 and returning array of object length is 1 so on the html side the two rows gets displayed.
How can I solve this issue ?
[image]

Html:

```
<div class="row pl-5 ml-1 pb-3 pt-2">
        <div class="col-md-4">
            <p>Search Results Found: {{filterMetadata.count}}</p>
        </div>
    </div>

   <div  *ngFor="let item of memberListData 
 |search:searchName:searchType:operatorType:filterMetadata">
       
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-11">
                <div class="member-card">
                <mat-card>
                    <div class="row pt-3">
                        <div class="col-md-3">
                            <h6>Member Name</h6>
                            <p>{{ item.member_name }}</p>
                        </div>
                       
                      <!--   <div class="col-md-2">
                            <h6>Last Name</h6>
                        <p>{{ item.LastName }}</p>
                        </div> -->
                        <div class="col-md-3">
                            <h6>Email ID</h6>
                            <p>{{ item.primary_email }}</p>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-2">
                            <h6>Member ID</h6>
                            <p>{{ item.contact_id }}</p>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-2">
                            <h6>Mobile No</h6>
                            <p>{{ item.mobile }}</p>
                        </div>
                       
                        <div class="col-md-1 card-button pt-1">
                            <button class="view-button" mat-raised-button color="primary" [routerLink]="['/member/', item.contact_id, item.contract_id]">View</button>
                        </div>
                   
                    </div>
```

searchPipe.ts

```
export class SearchPipe implements PipeTransform {

  transform(value: any, searchName:any, searchType?:any, operatorType?: any, filterMetadata?: any, ...args: any[]): any {
    if(!args) {
      return value;
    }
   
    if (searchName)
    {
      let rval = value.filter((val) =>(val.member_name.toLocaleLowerCase().includes(searchName) || (val.member_id.toString().includes(searchName)) || (val.contract_id.toString().includes(searchName) || (val.primary_email.toLowerCase().includes(searchName)) || (val.mobile.toString().includes(searchName)) ) ) )
      console.log(rval);
      filterMetadata.count = rval.length;
      return [rval, filterMetadata]

    }
```

}
}

Comment: Give an example of the date you are using. Also, the scenarios in which you are getting duplicate records.

Comment: Updated and given the example in question

Answer (score 0):

If it's only count registers, you can use in your *ngFor let i=index;let last=last and some like

```
<div  *ngFor="let item of memberListData...;let i=index;let last=last">
   <div class="row">...here your item...</div>
   <div *ngIf="last" class="total">{{i+1}}</div>
</div>
```

But in general you **should use two arrays**: one with all the elements and one with the filtered result and not use a pipe to filter results

Comment: I have to print the count outside the ngFor Loop